# Wordpress Warning: preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory

Tags: php, mac

I just have installed xampp with php 7.3.1 on mac with OS El capitan.

The problem that when i run a WordPress project will show:

> Warning: preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php
>   on line 2110 Warning: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more
>   memory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4947 Warning: preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more
>   memory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4843 Warning: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more
>   memory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4947 Warning: preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more
>   memory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4947

Comment: do you get more verbose errors in your error log.  seeing the stack trace on that would be helpful

Comment: I'm getting the same errors on my local installation. I have to refresh every new page load to temporarily hide the errors.

Comment: @PaulShryock I did downgrade to old php 7.1 and fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I added the following line to the `php.ini` and restarted Apache and it worked (Xampp on macOS):

```
pcre.jit=0
```

This disables PCRE's just-in-time compilation.

Further information:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.jit

If you can't find the location of `php.ini` and are using Xampp, go to localhost and select the PHP information link and it is displayed there.

Comment: This answer looks good - I would add a link to the manual for this specific option to add context: http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.jit

Comment: For me this didn't work. Then I added 'php_value pcre.jit 0' to my .htaccess and that fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me.  I would expect that the reason that it didn't work for @Niqql is that they changed the wrong php.ini file (there are often several and figuring out which one is the correct one)  That said, their solution is just as good.  Maybe even better because it only effects the site below it in the file tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need downgrade your php7.3 to php7.1 version. I have the same problem when trying to change php version to the upper.